# Проект Spring Boot в IntelliJ создается не той версии

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

такая проблема, создаю проект Spring Boot в IntelliJ, прописываю при создании 8 версию, но после создания в pom пишет версию 17, следовательно если не поменять ее на 8, проект не запустится:

> java: warning: source release 17 requires target release 17
>
> Module demo1 SDK 1.8 is not compatible with the source version 17.

а когда меняю, пишет что версия классов не соответствует версии:

> class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 52.0
>
> Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

как быть?

UPD:
Пробовал создавать проект через сайт спринга, но результат тот же

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 1):

Третий spring boot требует 17 версию JDK. При создании проекта выбери вторую версию spring boot